# How can I get iPhone OS 3.0 and 3.1 (I have iPhone Developer Program)

Tags: iphone

I have iPhone Developer Program.

And My iPod touch has iPhone OS 2.2.1.

I wanna update my touch to 3.0.

But I cannot find the link for getting iPhone OS 3.0

Please let me know how to get iPhone OS 3.0 and 3.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what yogsototh said, you can also launch the Organizer from within Xcode and, with your device plugged in, it should give you a link to the update location.

Comment: Thanks :) I have iPod2,1_3.1_7C116a_Restore.ipsw. But I got an error which message is "ERROR: Sending ramdisk to device: An error occurred performing DFU". So I cannot restore.. If you have any idea please let me know. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just launch iTunes and connect your iPod Touch. When clicking on the iPod touch icon you'll have the possibility to upgrade your OS.

Comment: Note that it costs 5-10$ though.